# Why can't a getElementById method find an element when imported inside functional component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to use this cool scroll effect in one of my pages.The functional component has the same exact HTML as in the [codepen](https://codepen.io/igstudio/pen/pbYOab). The script is in a separate file that is imported inside the component file.
The problem is this line doesn't work

```
var well = document.getElementById('well');
```

I tried to import the JS-file into a variable and the call it in a useEffect hook just to make sure that hte script is run after the DOM is rendered. But it still doesn't work.
What do I do to make the script work in my component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try importing the script like this ?

```
useEffect(() => {
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = "source of the js file";
    script.async = false;
    document.body.appendChild(script);
    return () => {
        document.body.removeChild(script);
      }
  }, []);
```

Comment: not yet, bu I'kk try and will let you know if it works :) thanks